failed to write data into buffer by buffer overflow action=:throw_exception

I have deployed fluentd as kubernetes pod to upload the kubernetes log to AWS OpenSearch.
Initially for first few days it was working properly(sending log to AWS OpenSearch), after few days the latest kubernetes logs was not available in AWS OpenSearch.
So when i checked the fluentd pod logs i was able to see the below error:

failed to write data into buffer by buffer overflow action=:throw_exception
Environment

Fluentd version:1.16.5
Operating system: Amazon Linux 2
Kernel version: 5.10.210-201.852.amzn2.x86_64

Configuration
<source>
  @type tail
  path /var/log/containers/*.log
  pos_file /var/log/fluentd-containers.log.pos
  tag kubernetes.*
  read_from_head true
  <parse>
    @type multi_format
    <pattern>
      format json
      time_key @timestamp
      time_format %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%NZ
    </pattern>
    <pattern>
      format /^(?<time>.+) (?<stream>stdout|stderr) [^ ]* (?<log>.*)$/
      time_format %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%N%:z
    </pattern>
  </parse>
</source>

<filter kubernetes.**>
  @type kubernetes_metadata
</filter>

<match kubernetes.**>
  @type opensearch
  include_tag_key true
  host "opensearch domain"
  port "443"
  scheme https
  ssl_verify true
  ssl_version TLSv1_2
  index_name services_log
  include_timestamp true
  tag_key @log_name
  time_key @timestamp
  time_format %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%NZ
  buffer_chunk_limit 2M
  buffer_queue_limit 32
  flush_interval 5s
  max_retry_wait 30
  disable_retry_limit
  num_threads 8
</match>

Error Log
2024-05-24 04:41:09 +0000 [warn]: #0 failed to write data into buffer by buffer overflow action=:throw_exception
2024-05-24 04:41:09 +0000 [warn]: #0 emit transaction failed: error_class=Fluent::Plugin::Buffer::BufferOverflowError error="buffer space has too many data" location="/fluentd/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/fluentd-1.16.5/lib/fluent/plugin/buffer.rb:330:in `write'" tag="kubernetes.var.log.containers.service.log"


I encountered similar issues while using on premise Elasticsearch. I resolved them by adjusting the following parameters:
buffer_chunk_limit 2M
buffer_queue_limit 32
flush_interval 5s

Additionally, I removed the fluentd logs from the loop by including this line in my source directive:
exclude_path /var/log/containers/fluentd*.log

